# Why does this seem to ignore the if statements and just print the statements even if they are false?

Tags: python, if-statement

So this program is supposed to ask for three numbers (R,G,B), that are larger than one and less than 255, and if they are larger than 255 or less than 0 it's supposed to print "R/G/B number is incorrect", but if it is larger than 0 and less than 255, it's supposed to output nothing. My problem is that no matter what number I input, it just prints the "R/G/B number is incorrect" phrase anyways.

Code (python)

```
r = input("Enter the red: ")
g = input("Enter the green: ")
b = input("Enter the blue: ")

if (r < 0 or r > 255):
    print("Red number is incorrect.")

if (g < 0 or g > 255):
    print("Green number is incorrect.")

if (b < 0 or b > 255):
    print("Blue number is incorrect.")
```

Some examples of output:

```
Enter the red: 20
Enter the green: 300
Enter the blue: -1
Red number is incorrect.
Green number is incorrect.
Blue number is incorrect.
```

***or***

```
Enter the red: 20
Enter the green: 20
Enter the blue: 20
Red number is incorrect.
Green number is incorrect.
Blue number is incorrect.
```

Comment: I surprised you didnt get an error.

Comment: What version of Python is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not converting them to numbers using `g = int(input(...))`

This should resolve the problem.

Note: in your example, it is comparing strings to numbers, which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Of course! Just waiting for the cooldown